# correct index for nested jsonp response

Tags: javascript, json, indexing

given this nested json response

```
{
"findCompletedItemsResponse":[  
  {  
     "ack":[  
        "Success"
     ],
     "version":[  
        "1.13.0"
     ],
     "timestamp":[  
        "2017-11-28T19:23:07.161Z"
     ],
     "searchResult":[  
        {  
           "@count":"2",
           "item":[  
              {  
                 "itemId":[  
                    "222664349999"
                 ],
                 "title":[  
                    "Nikon IK467-156 Remote Terminal Cover 10-Pin for  D2X, D2Xs, D2H, F5, F90, F100"
                 ],
                 "globalId":[  
                    "EBAY-ENCA"
                 ],

                 "galleryURL":[  
                    "http:\/\/thumbs4.ebaystatic.com\/m\/mvCz__whMmEvIJIvq0Li1qQ\/140.jpg"
                 ],
                 "viewItemURL":[  
                    "http:\/\/www.ebay.com\/itm\/Nikon-IK467-156-Remote-Terminal-Cover-10-Pin-D2X-D2Xs-D2H-F5-F90-F100-\/222664349999"
                 ],
                 "paymentMethod":[  
                    "PayPal"
                 ],
                 "autoPay":[  
                    "false"
                 ],
                 "postalCode":[  
                    "B2R1C3"
                 ],
                 "location":[  
                    "Canada"
                 ],
                 "country":[  
                    "CA"
                 ],

                 "sellingStatus":[  
                    {  
                       "currentPrice":[  
                          {  
                             "@currencyId":"CAD",
                             "__value__":"5.0"
                          }
                       ],
```

What would the index of *value* be? I am currently accessing everything above sellingStatus via this code:

```
 var items = result.findCompletedItemsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item || [];
 var html = [];

 html.push('<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3"><tbody>');
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
   var item     = items[i];
   var title    = item.title;
   var pic      = item["galleryURL"];
   var viewitem = item.viewItemURL;
   var sellPrice = item.sellingStatus[0]["currentPrice"]["_value_"];
```

I am trying to get sellPrice set to the value of the *value* entry in the json response but cannot seem to figure out the proper syntax to access the index.

Thanks for the responses. That method unfortunately did not work. Still trying to figure this out. I tried the following code as well but I am getting the same error:

```
var sellPrice=result.findCompletedItemsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item[0].sellingStatus[0].convertedCurrentPrice || [];
for (var j = 0; j < sellPrice.length; ++j) {
    var convertedCurrentPrice = sellPrice[j];

    var soldPrice = convertedCurrentPrice["_value_"];
```

For the record I am trying to access the convertedCurrentPrice value in the response, not the currentPrice value as I originally stated. Still no luck with this. Been searching around for tutorials as well but so far haven't found anything that goes deep into index nested jsonp from a request callback. Anyone know of any tutorials that cover this? Thanks again.

Comment: `currentPrice` is array...try `item.sellingStatus[0]["currentPrice"][0]["_value_"];`

Answer (score 0):

```
var sellPrice = item.sellingStatus[0]["currentPrice"][0]["_value_"];
```

CurrentPrice is an array with a single currency block in it